# Java Binary Search On A Large AbstractList

Tags: java, linked-list, abstract, binary-search

### Short Version:

I have a `LinkedList` of `n` random `Integer`s in ascending order.
If I use `Collections.binarySearch` on that list, it works fine for any `n` I've tried.
When I wrap that `LinkedList` with an `AbstractList` however, for `n>10000` the binary search starts to behave very strange.
Instead of running a proper binary search, it just iterates over the entire list.

---

### Long Version:

I have a `"file"` that contains random numbers in an ascending order, where each line holds one number.
I want to binary search that `"file"` and find the index (or `"line number"`) of a given number.

A trivial solution to that would be to read the entire file and put each number in a `LinkedList`, then use `Collections.binarySearch` on that `LinkedList`.

Now, lets say I'm given information that reading a line from that `"file"` is a costly operation.

What I tried to do, to minimize the times I have to read the `"file"`, is to "simulate" that `LinkedList`, and use an `AbstractList` where every time I use `get(int index)` in that `AbstractList` I just read the line `index` from the `"file"`.

This seemed to have worked pretty well when my `AbstractList` size is `<1000`, when I try a bigger list, the binary search seems to stop working, and just iterates over all of the `AbstractList` (from first node to the last).

---

I seem to have narrowed the problem down to using a large AbstractList with Binary Search.
I am not sure why this is happening, and would love some help.

I've included the "Long Version" in case someone would be able to suggest another solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Why on earth would any sane person do a binary search on a `LinkedList`?

Comment: I only used a LinkedList simulate my "file". You can change the LinkedList in my description to an array. The problem occurs for me when using the AbstractList, not the LinkedList.

Comment: Use a better "file". A `LinkedList` has `O(n)` `get()` - this is **the same** as a full traversal. So your "binary search` is no better than that reading the file line-by-line and finding the item - in fact its much worse! This approach has deeper problems than your "simulation". No one. Absolutely no one does a binary search on disk.

Comment: @BoristheSpider , binary search on an array list is pretty fast. The test took a long time, but I pulled out ALL 10 Million objects in random order and it averaged 1.1300091 milliseconds per get.  For 1Meg objects, it averaged 0.056 milliseconds.

Comment: @oldercoder I'm not disputing that binary search is fast. I'm saying that a binary search on a collection that has `O(n)` `get` is absurdly slow.

Comment: I posted it, but wasserman shot it down. I have it at log(n). Want the code?

Comment: @oldercoder you have what exactly at `O(log(n))`? `get` on a `LinkedList` is `O(n)`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider  comment the main functions you don't want in the test code. http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8178021

Comment: @oldercoder Isn't your data structure very much like a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))?

Comment: No. No left/right nodes, but it acts like a tree. 32 objects = 5 get() calls and it's using an ArrayList as the only container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Javadoc to the rescue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator)):

> [`binarySearch`] runs in log(n) time for a "random access" list (which provides near-constant-time positional access). If the specified list does not implement the `RandomAccess` interface and is large, this method will do an iterator-based binary search that performs O(n) link traversals and O(log n) element comparisons.

`LinkedList` and `AbstractList` don't implement `RandomAccess`.

Comment: Even less so the OP's random `AbstractList` hack!

Comment: I do wonder - is there ever a time when _not_ doing a full traversal is advantageous if binary searching a `List` that doesn't `implements RandomAccess`?

Comment: Hmm... this doesn't explain why the "problem" was only observed with the wrapper.

Comment: @shmosel I suspect that the OP only tried with the wrapper. OP to confirm.

Comment: @BoristheSpider *If I use `Collections.binarySearch` on that list, it works fine for any `n` I've tried.*

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't see any magic in the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.binarySearch%28java.util.List%2Cjava.lang.Object%29). Btw, `BINARYSEARCH_THRESHOLD` would indicate that the answer to your previous question is yes.

Comment: @Ungoliant " thought overloading "get" gives me that random access" it doesn't, but you can declare your `AbstractList` implementation as `class MyAbstractList<T> extends AbstractList<T> implements RandomAccess`, and then binary search will use index-based searching.

Comment: @AndyTurner That won't help anything if it's wrapping a `LinkedList`.

Comment: @Ungoliant You should be able to do a binary search on a `RandomAccessFile` without having to process the entire file. If you need more help, you should probably ask a new question.

Comment: @Ungoliant the problem isn't that `AbstractList` doesn't implement `RandomAccess`, because you can make it do so in your subclass, as I indicated in my comment. The problem is in the delegating the `get` call to something which *doesn't* implement `RandomAccess`.

Comment: @shmosel no, in fact it will make it worse, because every "random" array access will require iterating from the start of the list. I was just pointing out that you can make an `AbstractList` randomly-accessible.

Comment: @AndyTurner `RandomAccess` doesn't "make" the list randomly-acccessible. It's just a marker interface that hints to the implementation.

Comment: @shmosel yes yes, merely indicate that its implementation suits random access.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I figured out the difference between `LinkedList` and the wrapper. `AbstractList`'s iterator is indexed-based, making traversal quadratic for a non-random-access list! Of course, this completely thwarts the binary search's attempted optimization. I wonder if it would have been better to just copy the list into a temporary array.

Comment: @shmosel makes sense, `LinkedList` provides its own `Iterator`.